# Problems running and installing with restricted user rights

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I wrote a small application that is commercially used by an company. The application runs stable, but I am currently trying to get it to work on the companys computers after they have updated their security policy.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and publish the application as an One-Click Application. It works on my personal system and also had worked on the companys systems. Besides the .Net system libraries, I am using the File Dialog to save and load files, TCP sockets to communicate with one other software and read and write one registry key in the user space.

Before their policy switch, it was possible to install it and run it. After the switch they required Admin Rights to install it and it will work, but as soon as the IT department revokes the admin rights, the program will not launch.

I am a stuck, because the users I work with are not very technically versed and Information I get is usually not very helpful. It is also not very helpful that I can't reproduce the issue and at that point it is just stabbing in the dark.

So would be glad about any help regarding to fix it on my end, be it settings for the publishing process, information they can extract and send me, or how I would be able to reproduce it.

I tried a few things on changing how the application is published, but that didn't change if it runs after the revoked.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend working on two sides concurrently :

---

**First**, trying to have a usual process / documentation for the IT of your clients so that they are aware that your software needs admin rights.

It's not uncommon that some employees need some specific software, which requires elevated rights, while the IT department put restrictions on the actual user rights.

**You need to make the IT departments of your customers aware that your software falls into this category**. It's "their problem" to make it work, and for future clients you should even add some words about this in your contract.

This will ease the things if you give some clear, standard formatted documentation about this to your customers, so that they can forward it to their IT department for proper collaboration.

---

Of course, **in parallel**, you want to understand what is going on, and see if you can "fix as much as possible" yourself, as you are trying to do.

For that, a very good way is to have some "special users", some of your customers that you know are willing to help you by giving you reports of installation, because they have a more cheerful personality and/or are more technically savvy so they can easily give you some meaningful information.

With these users, you can try to experiment a bit more, add some proper logging to the installation process as much as you can and do rapid iterations to try to improve things.